# rubyzip file order

Tags: ruby, rubyzip

I am making an archive for a directory, where each file has a name with 3 digits starting from 001 to 049. My code is the following:

```
Zip::ZipFile.open(File.join(out, dir+".cbz"), Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) {
  |zipfile|
  Dir.glob(File.join(dir, "*")).sort.each {
    |file|
    puts "add file #{file}"
    zipfile.add(File.basename(file),file)
  }
}
```

When adding the files, I verified with `puts` that they are added in numerically ascending order.
But when I try to decompress them with `zip`, I found that they are decompressed in a random order (eg. 045, 002, ...).

How can I ensure that they decompress in the numerical order?

Edit: Taking a look at the produced zip file with a hex editor shows that the images are added in no sensible order, but that they are extracted via `unzip` in the order they a present in the central directory (block at the end of the zip file).

Comment: Why does it matter what order they decompress?

Comment: The program is generating CBZ (comic book files) and the reader program is sensitive to the order in the zip file rather than the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have traced this to an issue in the rubyzip library, whereby the entries array was not being sorted prior to being written to the central directory, but `unzip` was dependent on this order.

Fixed, and [sent a pull request upstream.](https://github.com/aussiegeek/rubyzip/pull/7)